# Using PHP and MySQL to separate column names and values in different areas

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to have one select tag and one input. When I select a column in the drop down list box, the corresponding value of that column should appear in an input box. I want to have the ability to modify the input field and post to a txt file. But just for now, I can’t seem to get how to use one query and in the html code separate from what is a column name and what is a value. That seems intensive logic going on, there has to be a simpler way of doing it. Could I use a variable from the first query that is inputted into a second query statement that retrieves this value and appears in an input form? I do not know how to integrate this. Any help would be most appreciated. My php and html code is posted below. You will see that queryAlarms and queryAlarmsL is practically the same. This is where I am unsure as to what is more efficient using one query or two. Thank you for your time.

```
<?php
    include_once 'DbConnect.php';
    function connect(){
        mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die ('Could not connect to the database unfortunately' .mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    }


    function close(){
        mysql_close();
    }


    function querySensors (){
        $myData = mysql_query("Select TEMPERATURE,HUMIDITY, CO2, PH From ANALOG_SENSORS ORDER BY ArduinoTime DESC LIMIT 1;");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo'<option value="' . $record['TEMPERATURE'] . '">' . $record['TEMPERATURE'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['HUMIDITY'] . '">' . $record['HUMIDITY'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['CO2'] . '">' . $record['CO2'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['PH'] . '">' . $record['PH'] .'</option>';
        }

    }


    function queryAlarmsL (){
        $myData = mysql_query("Select ArduinoTime, Alarm1A, Alarm1B, Alarm2A, Alarm2B, CycleTime, Setpoint From ANALOG_SENSORS ORDER BY ArduinoTime DESC LIMIT 1;");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo'<option value=`$ArduinoTime`>Arduino Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$Alarm1A`>Alarm 1 On Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$Alarm1B`>Alarm 1 Off Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$Alarm2A`>Alarm 2 On Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$Alarm2B`>Alarm 2 Off Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$CycleTime`>Cycle Time</option>/n';
            echo'<option value=`$Setpoint`>PH Setpoint 1</option>/n';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['ArduinoTime'] . '">' .  $record['ArduinoTime'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm1A'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm1A'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm1B'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm1B'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm2A'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm2A'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm2B'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm2B'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['CycleTime'] . '">' .  $record['CycleTime'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Setpoint'] . '">' .  $record['Setpoint'] .'</option>';
        }

    }


    function queryAlarms (){
        $myData = mysql_query("Select ArduinoTime, Alarm1A, Alarm1B, Alarm2A, Alarm2B, CycleTime, Setpoint From ANALOG_SENSORS ORDER BY ArduinoTime DESC LIMIT 1;");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
            echo'<option value="' . $record['ArduinoTime'] . '">' .  $record['ArduinoTime'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm1A'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm1A'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm1B'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm1B'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm2A'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm2A'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Alarm2B'] . '">' .  $record['Alarm2B'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['CycleTime'] . '">' .  $record['CycleTime'] .'</option>';
            echo'<option value="' . $record['Setpoint'] . '">' .  $record['Setpoint'] .'</option>';
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Here is the Html Code

```
<?php
   include_once 'DbFunction.php';
   connect();

   ?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Test TEMP</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <h1 align="center"> Trial of Temp </h1>
      </header>
      <section>
         <article>
            <hgroup>
            </hgroup>
            <p align="center";style="position:absolute; bottom:110px;>
            <select name="dropdown">
            <?php querySensors () ?>                
            </select>
            </p>
         </article>
         <article>
            <br>
            <table>
               <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:100%; text-align: center">
               <ul>
               <select name1="dropdown1">
                  <ul>
                  <?php queryAlarmsL() ?>               
               </select>
         </article>
         <article>
         <p align="center">
         <ul>  <select name2="dropdown2"><ul>
         <?php queryAlarms() ?>             
         </select>
         </article>
         </table>
         <?php close() ?>
         </p>
         </article>
         <article>
         </article>
      </section>
      <aside>
         <!--SideBar here -->
      </aside>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with OOP concepts in PHP? & mysql_* is not at all recommended. I suggest you take a look at this: https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class

Answer (score 0):

use fetch_assoc() instead of fetch array and it should work.

also for the sake of your security update to MYSQLI driver as mysql* is deprecated.
: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php
and you haven't used your connect() function, so you're not connected to the sql.

Comment: The connect function is located at the top of the html file. It is connected to MySQL. The original question was pertaining to how to use a selection box filled with column names to be able when selected populate its last row of value in an input field. This is what I am having issues with